# Get my radlistcontrol item from point

Tags: c#, .net, telerik

I have `Radlistcontrol` with items inside and added `Menu` with some options and i try to get my file path after clicked on `RadMenuItem` right click
This is what i have try so far but currently i am stuck.

```
RadListControl radListControl1;

RadMenuItem menuItemPlayFile = new RadMenuItem("Remove");
menuItemPlayFile.Click += menuItemPlayFile_Click;
radContextMenu1.Items.Add(menuItemPlayFile);

private void menuItemRemve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point point = radListControl1.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);            
    RadElement clickedItem = radListControl1.ElementTree.GetElementAtPoint(point);      
}
```

I try `Telerik` forums but it seems that this forum is dead.

Anyone may have some idea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  var clickedItem = radListControl1.ElementTree.GetElementAtPoint(e.Location) as RadListVisualItem;
  if (clickedItem == null)
    return;
  var dataItem = clickedItem.Data;
```

This will work for you as it basically does the same as  'ctrl.SelectedItem' but obtains the element under the mouse location without being actually selected.